# find command not working from other directory

Tags: unix

My dir sturcture that looks like

x

```
   /log

   /bin
```

I am giving this command from dir- x/bin

```
find ../log -type f -name \*.log  -mtime +90 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

(to find and display list of files older than 90 days.)  and it doesn't display anything.

Whereas if i execute same command in dir- x/log

```
find . -type f -name \*.log  -mtime +90 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

it gives me a list of files older than 90 days.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that paths are relative.

If you have a dir sturcture that looks like

```
 x
   /log
   /bin
```

AND your're in x/bin then you need to give the relative path to x/log, ie

```
 pwd
 x/bin
find ../x/log -type f -name \*.log  -mtime +90 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you mean- from pwd  x/bin                                                            find ../log -type f -name \*.log  -mtime +90 -exec ls -l {} \;       I tried this,but it doesn't work

Comment: So do you disagree with the dir structure map I have included? If so, please update your question. We're left to guess what the real problem is. Good luck.

Comment: Your directory structure map is correct.  I am giving relative path to x/log in x/bin ie. "find ../log" and the command doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions.
    First, escape the * using \*.  If you have any log files in current dir, they will get expanded before the command is executed.
    Second, I think you mean find ../x/log ...?